# Workaround to Android Market Cache Limits on Some Devices

Tags: android, google-play

We recently released a game on the Android Market and it's about 41MB in size.  We received reports that users of some devices are unable to install the app (though sadly it still allows them to purchase it.)

Researching the issue we found that these devices have some sort of cache limit applied to downloads from the Google Market and our app is larger than that limit.

Based on reports these are the limits we've so far determined:

- Samsung Galaxy S1, Galaxy Tab 7, and Captivate running Android 2.2 have a 30MB limit
- HTC Desire/S/HD running Android 2.2 has a 40MB limit

Apparently this restriction only applies to the Google Market because Amazon users can download the game without issue and it runs fine on the devices themselves (tested with no problems.)

Looking for a solution to this barrier. The suggestion I keep hearing is to split up the assets and download them separately after install. That seems messy but I'll be forced to go that route unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to emulate this problem for testing?

Comment: found a solution for this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

On my Huawey device this limit is caused by `/cache` "partition" size. Market downloads entire apk into `/cache` before installing them. As it has only 30MB, Market refuses to download larger apk, claiming it is out of space, even without any other app installed and plenty of space on `/data` partition.

Workaround: obtain apk file from non-market source and install it.